# How to update Apigility from 1.0.3 to 1.1.1?

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php, updates, laminas-api-tools

I'm using Apigility in version `1.0.3`:

```
$ composer show -i
...
zfcampus/zf-apigility               1.0.3              Apigility module for ZF2
zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin         1.1.2              Apigility Admin module
zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin-ui      1.1.4              Apigility Admin UI module
zfcampus/zf-apigility-documentation 1.0.5              Apigility API documentation module
zfcampus/zf-apigility-provider      1.0.1              Apigility interfaces
...
```

The currently newest version is `1.1.1`. **Ho to make an update?**

I've tried to do that via a `composer.json` edit:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.23",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.4",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility": "~1.0", -> changed to "~1.1"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This attempt resulted in an error:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package zfcampus/zf-apigility could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin 1.1.2 requires zfcampus/zf-apigility ~1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin 1.1.2 requires zfcampus/zf-apigility ~1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin >=1.1.2,<2.0.0 -> satisfiable by zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin[1.1.2].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think the latest version of Apigility is 1.1.1? https://packagist.org/packages/zfcampus/zf-apigility shows 1.0.3 (which you already have) as the latest version, as does the [Github repository](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility).

It's the [skeleton application](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-skeleton/releases), that's at version 1.1.1.

Comment: I have this info from the [Apigility website](https://apigility.org/), that is offering to "[download Apigility 1.1.1](http://prntscr.com/7l4buy)".

Comment: Ah, it's the skeleton application that's at version 1.1.1. That's at https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-skeleton I agree that it's a little confusing.